# How get acces to the current element in a directive with angular 2 and only javascript

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I am in angular 2 with Javascript.

In a directive, I need to access the current element in order to manipulate the DOM.

Notice that I cannot use the trick with the hashtag (`#element`)  because I will have a lot of elements like this. Each one will have my directive.

Html

```
<p [focus]="p1.focus"></p>
<p [focus]="p2.focus"></p>
<!-- ... -->
```

Javascript

```
(function (app) {

app.Focus =
ng.core.Directive({
    selector: "[focus]",
    inputs: ['focus'],
}).Class({
    constructor: function() {
        // how get access to the current element here
    }
})
})(window.app || (window.app = {}));
```

Do you know how I can do it ?

Unfortunately, official documentation is not very clear for javascript

Comment: Did you try to use `this`?

Comment: `this` returns the directives but not the current element in the DOM.

Comment: Can i show you in typescript? would you be able to convert it?

Comment: I am trying to learn angular 2 in javascript because I already know angular 2 in typscript. So I tried in the constructor but it doesn't work :x. But Why not

Comment: I do not know how to use with JS but I think you should use the ElementRef from @angular/core. You can see how to use it with JS here https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/quickstart.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My mistake, I forget injection in javascript. The good answer is :

```
constructor: [ ng.core.ElementRef, function(elementRef) {
      // elementRef.nativeElement

}]
```

Comment: You can mark you answer as the rigth one if it solves your problem!

Answer (score 4):

I don't know how to write this code in **javascript** but if this **typescript** code can help you.

```
 import { Component, ElementRef,Renderer } from '@angular/core';


 @Directive({
    selector: "[focus]",
    inputs: ['focus'],
     host: {
    '(click)':'click()',   
   },   
})

export class myDirective{
    constructor(private el:ElementRef) {
       console.log(el)//<-----------current element
    }
    click(){
       console.log(this.el) //<------------current element
    }
}
```

Comment: Here are some tips to use pure JS: https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/quickstart.html

Comment: @vinagreti Thanks man but the problem is I don't want to go ahead with JS.

Comment: Thank you @micronyks. Just seeing me the typescript version reminds me the injection of dependency.

Answer (score 0):

I use this javascript to change the css file for the active theme.  Maybe you can adapt this:

```
var KetoApp = {
    changeTheme: function(event, element) {
        var theme = $(element).data("theme"),
        themeLink = $('link[href$="theme.css"]'),
        newThemeURL =  'node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/' + theme + '/theme.css';

        themeLink.attr('href', newThemeURL);
        event.preventDefault();
    }
};
```